# namespace or module FsCheck is not defined

Tags: f#, mono, paket

I am starting to get my hands dirty with F# on Mac OS X but can't make it to work (F# version is 3.1 and Mono version is 4.0.2). I am using [packet](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) for dependency management and have already installed some libraries. This is how my `packet.dependencies` file looks like:

```
source https://nuget.org/api/v2

nuget Neo4jClient >= 1.0.0.664
nuget FsCheck
```

After `mono .paket/paket.exe install` I get related dependencies successfully downloaded into a `packages` folder. The auto-generated `packet.lock` file looks like the following:

```
NUGET
  remote: https://nuget.org/api/v2
  specs:
    FsCheck (2.0.5)
      FSharp.Core (>= 3.1.2.5)
    FSharp.Core (4.0.0.1)
    Microsoft.Bcl (1.1.10)
      Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.14)
    Microsoft.Bcl.Build (1.0.21)
    Microsoft.Net.Http (2.2.29)
      Microsoft.Bcl (>= 1.1.10)
      Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.14)
    Neo4jClient (1.0.0.664)
      Microsoft.Net.Http
      Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.3)
    Newtonsoft.Json (7.0.1)
```

I am trying to reference such libraries within my .fs files:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "./packages/FsCheck/lib/net45/FsCheck.dll"
#endif

open FsCheck
```

`open FsCheck` statement fails with `The namespace or module 'FsCheck' is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Switching to `.fsx` (instead of `.fs`) and removing the `#if` part works fine. With `.fs` it compiles but when running the `.exe` I get the following exception (I understand it means the `.dll` isn't bundled by default, in which case I wonder what the common practice is):

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FsCheck, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

Comment: What is giving you that error? F# Interactive, or the compiler?

Comment: I think normally a build system is used to copy dependencies to the output directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is missing the version. It should be

```
#r "./packages/FsCheck.2.0.5/lib/net45/FsCheck.dll"
```

Comment: still getting the same problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have a paket.references file in your project?
2. Did you add "FsCheck" to it?
3. Have you set the target framework of your project to .NET 4.5?

If you are using Xamarin Studio, your project target framework is probably set to .NET 4.0. You can change this in Project Options > Build > General.

You can also specify the target framework in paket.dependencies. You need step 3 though.

```
framework: net45
source https://nuget.org/api/v2

nuget Neo4jClient >= 1.0.0.664
nuget FsCheck
```